# Distraction free writing mode and vertically centered?

Tags: spacemacs, evil

One feature, that I really adored in Ulysses is it's typewriting scroll center lock mode (for the lack of a better description). It would keep the line centered, no matter if the cursor is at the beginning of a file or anywhere else: [image]

I can get vertical center in Emacs just fine, but not at the beginning of a buffer:

[image]

Is there any way to get the current line centered, even at the beginning of the buffer? So, centered-cursor-mode is almost perfect, except for beginning of the buffer. Or is that a limitation of how Emacs works?

Comment: AFAIK, the only way to make the text at the beginning of the buffer appear in the middle of the window instead of at the top would be to use a `display` text or overlay property (and adjust it as you move down among the lines, until it vanishes when there are enough lines between the current line and the top to fill the window. Perhaps someone will offer you code that does that.